# Social-Bootstrap Icons using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create social button icons similar to the ones outlined in this quick outline. 
http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

I've created a link to the Font Awesome cdn in my  and another link to the social-bootstrap.css sheet I downloaded using Bower and that I've migrated into the project folder. When I input code for just the icon I get a colored box to appear but no icon. Please help!

```
  <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </a>
```

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle?

Comment: Np!  https://jsfiddle.net/Ehnelson206/8d8qfz3z/

Looks like the output tab includes the icon, perhaps due to competing css sheets?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues here:

Firstly, when you use external resources (bootstrap, bootstrap-social, etc) in JSFiddle you should use the 'external resources' box on the left, and make sure that you reference https versions so that the requests aren't blocked.

Next, double check that your button HTML structure matches that on the demo site:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-dropbox">
    <i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i> Sign in with Dropbox
</a>
```

Finally, these will default to full width so I've wrapped them in a container, row and width div in order to control the width to half the available space.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8d8qfz3z/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Just starting out so your feedback is really appreicated. I'll be sure to go back and try this again with some of the pointers you made. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries - it can seem like a mountain of things to learn in the beginning but stick with it and you'll get there :)

In future, if you ever find that you have a working demo but your own version isn't working, the three things to check are:

1) Does my HTML match the demo (obviously the rest of the page doesn't need to match, use Chrome Inspector to inspect the demo button and move outwards)

2) Are all the assets (styles, scripts) being included (use the Network tab to check for 404s)

3) Are there any errors (check the Console)

Best of luck!